# htaccess 301 redirect entire site but with exceptions

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am trying to create an htaccess file to redirect my entire site except with some exceptions, but I can't get it working. I need to redirect the entire thing, provide a specific redirect, and exclude two pages. Below is my non-working sample. Thanks!

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/events/index.html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/calendar/index.html
Redirect 301 /info/faq.html http://mynewsite.com/my-page
Redirect 301 / http://mynewsite.com
```

Comment: See this (301 Redirect domain with  exception ) https://helponnet.com/2021/05/01/redirect-domain-with-exception/

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You're attempting to mix `mod_rewrite` with `mod_alias`, but the `RewriteCond` statements cannot condition the `Redirect` statements, as they don't come from the same module.

I believe you want something more like this, if I've correctly understood what you were trying to accomplish:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/events/index.html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/calendar/index.html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/info/faq.html
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://mynewsite.com/$0 [R=301,L]

Redirect 301 /info/faq.html http://mynewsite.com/my-page
```

Comment: I am trying to accomplish a variation of this - I want to redirect everything, unless the request is in to a specific directory (could be various file types) -- but it is not working:
[code]
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/sites/default/files/imports
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://mynewsite.com/$0 [R=301,L]

Redirect 301 / http://mynewsite.com/
[/code]

Comment: Try `%{REQUEST_URI} !^/sites/default/files/imports`, as the `!=` only works with exact string comparisons.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar issue.  Trying to redirect an entire domain with the exception of its robots.txt file.  Tim's answer didn't work for me, but this did

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule robots.txt - [L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://www.newsite.com/$0 [R=301,L]
```