# .htaccess redirect all urls to x except redirect 1 to y and allow some to stay as is

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I am changing the domain name of a site and would like to redirect majority of traffic to the new site. However, 1 I'd like to send to a different url. And, allow a few to stay as is.

Redirects:

1. oldurl . com --> newurl . com
2. oldurl . com / * --> newurl . com / *
3. oldurl . com / special --> specialurl . com

No redirects:

4. oldurl . com / robots.txt --> oldurl . com / robots.txt

Here is what I have so far which allows me to achieve #1-3 of the above examples:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/special
RewriteRule (.*) http://specialurl.com [R=301,L]
RewriteRule (.*) https://newurl.com/$1?utm_medium=301&utm_source=oldurl.com [R=301,L]
```

I tried adding the line below before ^/special to achieve #4 but did not work:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/robots.txt
```

Is it possible to achieve #4? What I'm hoping to do is allow robots.txt and Google's verification html to exist on this old url to continue using Webmaster Tools for domain change purposes.

Thx in advance

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20504241/793549) by tomhoeck:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule robots.txt - [L]
RewriteRule google1234.html - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/special
RewriteRule (.*) http://specialurl.com [R=301,L]
RewriteRule (.*) https://newurl.com/$1?utm_medium=301&utm_source=oldurl.com [R=301,L]
```

The RewriteRule robots.txt - [L] etc. now allows the pages to show without a redirect.